PySpark how to process two streams which are processed independently
I'm using pyspark and kafka to perform some stream operations. I have two topics, each for each Kafka stream, and I use pyspark to work on that streams.
stream1 = read_from_kafka("topic1")
stream2 = read_from_kafka("topic2")
query1 = stream1.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(my_fun1) \
    .start()

query2 = stream2.writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(my_fun2) \
    .start()

my_fun1 and my_fun2 are the same, it takes sample from stream batch and calculate some operations and log results. And it works independently for each stream. But in some situations, I want to compare the result between sample from stream1 and sample from stream2. How should I do it? Is it possible in pyspark to operate on both stream same time? I want to do it without using method like busy waiting (its my only idea).
I tried using join on both streams, but it's not exactly what I want (there is problem with sampling from joined streams), I want to operate on exactly these two samples which I got in my funcs

Can you elaborate on the operation you're doing, and what it means to compare the results in some situations? My guess is that you want to union these streams together and operate on them, but don't know for sure without more detail.
